# HTML(input)->php->mysql->php->json->HTML render

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

**Description of problem:** I want to get value from HTML input with php and to run query on mysql database: SELECT * FROM WHERE (value=value of ID in HTML input)

**WHAT I TRY TO DO:**
I write HTML input:

```
  <input id="akt_djubrenje" type="text" value="1">
```

THEN I WRITE PHP:

```
try {
      /* Establish the database connection */
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM akt_djubrenje WHERE ID_akt = :akt_djubrenje");
     $result->execute(array(':akt_djubrenje' => $_POST['akt_djubrenje']));
...
...
etc.
```

ALSO I give a php file data of input fields and call php file with AJAX:

```
    function tabela() {

    $.ajax({
            url: 'getdjubrenje.php', // make this url point to the data file
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{akt_djubrenje:$("#akt_djubrenje").val()},
            async: false,
            success:function(json){
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
            alert (json);
  // Create and draw the visualization.
  visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tabela_djubrenje'));
  visualization.draw(data, {'allowHtml': true});
            }
        });
}
```

My problem is with **HOW TO GET INPUT field VALUE from HTML and fetch with php/ajax**

When I type exactly value etc. "1" instead `$_POST` ... all works fine, so problem is with this code.
Anybody have some idea to solve my problem?

Comment: "*When I type exactly value etc. "1" instead $_POST ... all works fine*". You don't use `$_POST` anywhere. If you submit your form with POST you need to change the `$_GET` param to a `$_POST` param.

Comment: sorry I change that but again dont work

Comment: I get this error: ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':akt_djubrenje' at line 1

Comment: Then your code isn't what you posted. In the code you posted you use `:ajdi`.

Comment: in browser console i dont get any error

Comment: also my input ID and data in ajax is I think OK

Comment: You need to post your actual code, because the SQL error you get is **not** from that SQL query. There's no query in your code containing `:akt_djubrenje`.

Comment: here is my full HTML+Jquery ajax code (on the end of document) http://agroagro.com/aktivnosti1.html

Comment: but my input ID is akt_djurenje and I use it as data in ajax request,             data:{akt_djubrenje:$("#akt_djubrenje").val()},

Comment: Your **php** code is wrong. You can't get an error saying "there's an error near `:akt_djubrenje`" when `:akt_djubrenje` isn't present in your PHP code. Your code you posted has no `:akt_djubrenje` - hence you **cannot** get that error. It's impossible. You need to show your ACTUAL PHP code and not whatever you posted here, because whatever you posted here would never give that error.

Comment: sorry I will update it now, but no work again

Comment: I update php now in answer ...

Comment: You still need to use `$_GET`. You still haven't.

Comment: where I need to use GET? on php file $_GET [] ???

Comment: `$result->execute(array(':akt_djubrenje' => $_GET['akt_djubrenje']));`

Comment: I try that but dont work, also in my ajax jquery code i add:    type: 'GET',

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you use [`PDO::query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) and then try to bind variables. That's now how `query()` works:

> PDO::query() executes an SQL statement in a single function call, returning the result set (if any) returned by the statement as a PDOStatement object.

Hence it tries to execute the query right away, not waiting for your `execute()` call. This is why you get "*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `:akt_djubrenje` at line 1.*".

What you should do is use [`PDO::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) in order to prepare queries and bind variables:

```
 $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM akt_djubrenje WHERE ID_akt = :akt_djubrenje");
 //               ^^^^^^
 $result->execute(array(':akt_djubrenje' => $_POST['akt_djubrenje']));
```

Comment: I try both solution but again is the same - dont work... thanks for helping. I really dont know what can be issue here!

Comment: @gmaestro Look in your network tab. Is it being transfered as the correct type (GET/POST). Are the variables inside the request?

Comment: IMG of network tab: http://i.imgur.com/KHdFyuy.png, also you can see network tab at http://agroagro.com/aktivnosti1.html

Comment: @gmaestro You need to click on the `POST` request to see the headers being sent/received.

Comment: can you do that on my example: http://agroagro.com/aktivnosti1.html and see what can be a problem? please help

Comment: i get this: Request URL:http://agroagro.com/getdjubrenje.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,bg;q=0.6,hr;q=0.4,sr;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:15
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:_ga=GA1.2.834929442.1393540797; PH_HPXY_CHECK=s1
Host:agroagro.com
Origin:http://agroagro.com
Referer:http://agroagro.com/aktivnosti1.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36

Comment: @gmaestro And can you once again post your **exact** PHP code that you have **right** now?

Comment: $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM akt_djubrenje WHERE ID_akt = :akt_djubrenje");
  $result->execute(array(':akt_djubrenje' => $_POST['akt_djubrenje']));

Comment: when I write this:   $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM akt_djubrenje WHERE ID_akt = 1"); then all works fine

Comment: @gmaestro What does `var_dump($_POST['akt_djubrenje']);` output?

Comment: i really dont know, where is that ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48807/discussion-between-h2ooooooo-and-gmaestro)

Comment: very much to h200000!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are submitting your request as GET instead of POST. Because you haven't included the sending type as POST in $.ajax. Please correct it.

add option `type="POST"` in your $.ajax({...,});

instead of

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM akt_djubrenje WHERE ID_akt = :akt_djubrenje");
$result->execute(array(':akt_djubrenje' => $_POST['akt_djubrenje']));
```

add

```
 $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM akt_djubrenje WHERE ID_akt = ?");
 $result->execute(array($_POST['akt_djubrenje']));
```

Comment: how, where i need to type this?

Comment: your php code accept post data because you used $_POST in php

Comment: dont work i again get the same error: ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':akt_djubrenje' at line 1

Comment: I quit, again dont work, soory for boring you, and thanks for heping me